# TexLive 2018: latexmk does not work (seems to crash) - How to debug?

Tags: latexmk, texlive-2018

I switched to texlive 2018 yesterday.

My Build-Environment: Win64, Texstudio, latexmk, lualatex, biber.

I tried to compile a test document  - it worked fined using my old TL-17 and the new TL-18 installation.

Today I updated the TL-18 installation (using: `tlmgr update --all`). Now latexmk does not work anymore - I guess it crashes. I guess, because I don't get any output and I don't know how to further debug the problem:

Calling latexmk manually (e.g. `latexmk --help`) reports nothing: no help, no error message is printed. latexmk delivered with TL-17 still works fine - see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it works Ok in cygwin tl2018, could be an issue with the windows build, perhaps raise on the texlive list

Comment: I also experienced this TeX Live 2018 bug, which appeared with the today update.

Comment: `perl path/to/latexmk.pl` answers so only the wrapper seems to be broken.

Comment: It already has been reported to the texlive mailing list: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-May/041574.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems latexmk.exe finds the wrong script.

What it should look for is

```
texmf-dist/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl
```

However,

```
texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/extensions/latexmk.lua
```

is found instead.

If you do not use make4ht, one workaround is to rename `latexmk.lua`
(for example to `latexmkX.lua`).

Source:
http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-May/041580.html

---

**UPDATE:** The author of make4ht has renamed `latexmk` extension to `latexmk_build` in version 0.2b.

Comment: according http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-May/041592.html this workaround soon shouldn't be needed anymore.